# CONFIG_LOCALVERSION (CentOS 6.5)

Tags: linux, centos

I am in `/boot` as "root". I edit `config-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_46` and added my name to `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="John"`

But when I type `uname -r` is just shows the version, but not my name at the end. Am I editing the wrong config file?

Comment: Change your title for better response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you are editing is merely a record of the config of the kernel when it was compiled.  The only way a change here would work is if you were to prepare your system to compile a new kernel and copy the file from `/boot` to the kernel source tree in order to use it as the kernel options during the compilation process.

The config file is simply used to decide how to build the kernel and to pass a few options (such as `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION`).  For example, the first line on my current config is:

```
CONFIG_64BIT=y
```

which told the kernel build process to compile for a 64 bit computer.  If you look through the file you'll see many options that enable (`y`) or disable (`n`) an option and for drivers allow you to build as a loadable module (`m`).

The file thererfore doesn't reside in the kernel - it defines the kernel at build time.  Nothing more, nothing less.  Once the kernel is compiled, the file is effectively redunant.  They are stored in `/boot` so that a similar kernel can be rebuilt later without going through each individual option and deciding on their values from scratch. There are 4448 lines that begin with `CONFIG` in my current config file - deciding on each one would be rather laborious and error prone.  Instead, I could copy this file into the kernel build tree and change the few settings I need to change then rebuild the kernel.

As `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION` is hard coded in at compile time, it cannot be changed. It can only be read by the `uname` command, or as g4ur4v said, from the proc filesystem at `/proc/sys/kernel`.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is there a way to find where the config file is in the current kernel?

Answer (score 2):

`uname -r` takes data from `/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease` .

You cannot modify this file.

`/boot` is used when you want to compile a new kernel, so changing file there has no effect on the running kernel.

Comment: Ok, but can I still view the current kernel's config file? Where is it located?